# RW-locking a Windows file in Python, so that at most one test instance runs per night

Tags: python, windows, race-condition, file-locking

I have written a custom test harness in Python (existing stuff was not a good fit due to lots of custom logic). Windows task scheduler kicks it off once per hour every day. As my tests now take more than 2 hours to run and are growing, I am running into problems. Right now I just check the system time and do nothing unless `hour % 3 == 0`, but I do not like that. I have a text file that contains:

```
# This is a comment
LatestTestedBuild = 25100

# Blank lines are skipped too
LatestTestRunStartedDate = 2011_03_26_00:01:21

# This indicates that it has not finished yet.
LatestTestRunFinishDate =
```

Sometimes, when I kick off a test manually, it can happen at any time, including 12:59:59.99
I want to remove race conditions as much as possible. I would rather put some extra effort once and not worry about practical probability of something happening. So, I think locking a this text file atomically is the best approach.

I am using `Python 2.7`, `Windows Server 2008R2 Pro` and `Windows 7 Pro`. I prefer not to install extra libraries (`Python` has not been "sold" to my co-workers yet, but I could copy over a file locally that implements it all, granted that the license permits it).

So, please suggest a good, bullet-proof way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start running a test make a file called `__LOCK__` or something. Delete it when you finish, using a try...finally block to ensure that it always gets cleared up. Don't run the test if the file exists. If the computer crashes or similar, delete the file by hand. I doubt you need more cleverness than that.

Are you sure you need 2 hours of tests?! I think 2 minutes is a more reasonable amount of time to spend, though I guess if you are running some complicated numerics you might need more.

example code:

```
import os
if os.path.exists("__LOCK__"):
    raise RuntimeError("Already running.") # or whatever
try:
    open("__LOCK__", "w").write("Put some info here if you want.")
finally:
    if os.path.exists("__LOCK__"):
        os.unlink("__LOCK__")
```

Comment: Thanks. Unit tests are usually quick, but once you get up to several thousands of them, the time starts to add up noticeably. If you are driving a GUI app, which is a pain for a whole bunch of other reasons, then it can take 2 minutes per test easily. GUI tests can also refuse to stop running if something goes wrong. At its most complex there are several windows services and GUI apps interacting.
 This is why I wanted to be able to detect old locks and try to kill things and clean things up and/or send out an email notifying interested parties about this particular event. Any further thoughts?